# node.js , mongodb, mongoose, html how can i insert data(in index.html)?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase'); //connect database

/* *
 * *    Define UserSchema
 * **/

var UserSchema = new Schema({
user_id : String,
email : String,
base_location : Number,
user_type : String,
number_of_event : Number
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var user  =new User


app.post('/api/users', function (req, res){
var product;
console.log("User: ");
console.log(req.body);
user = new ProductModel({
user_id: req.body.user_id,
email: req.body.email,
base_location: req.body.base_location,
});
product.save(function (err) {
if (!err) {
return console.log("created");
} else {
return console.log(err);
}
});
return res.send(user);
});
```

this is my app.js 
 it contains schema and post function 
 i don't know how can i use this file in html 
 i want to make indext.html which can insert user data 
 how can i do that? 
 3421

423

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude a possibilities. What I usually do is create an [express server](http://expressjs.com/) and attach the routes to special functions in express.

```
//your modules
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connect mongo
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase');

//schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
 user_id : String,
 email : String,
 base_location : Number,
 user_type : String,
 number_of_event : Number
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var user  =new User

app.post('/api/users', function (req, res){
  //do your stuff
});

app.listen(80);
```

You then will need to run the above script (lets call it **app.js**) with

```
node app.js
```

If the code above is sane, this will run the server. When you connect to the server with the app then you will receive a connection. You should also look up some docs on [socketIO](http://socket.io/).